# Does the D7200's 1.3x image area setting crop a RAW file in-camera?

Tags: nikon, post-processing, raw, crop-factor

Apologies for the poor explanation, I'm a Pentax guy so not very familiar with Nikon gear, and have been asked if there is any way to fix this problem.

My MIL has a Nikon D7200 which has had the "Image Area" option set wrong (to 1.3x) in the menu for quite a while (the camera is new to her as well). This has meant that the viewfinder has been showing a much larger area than is captured, and many shots have missed edges.

As I understand it, the image area affects the amount of the sensor which is used? Is that correct? It has two options "DX" and "1.3x" so I assume it's a way to choose the crop of the sensor.

The photos were taken as RAW (NEF), and the RAW images suggest that the pixel count is the same between images with/without the image area set to 1.3x. Is this fixable in post processing? Or are the photo subjects permanently decapitated?

Comment: What happens when you open the pictures in a RAW processing software?

Comment: "the RAW images suggest that the pixel count is the same between images with/without the image area set to 1.3x." - how did you know that?

Comment: @PinhollowEuri - the in camera info display for the images showed them both as having the same pixel dimensions (although as a non Nikon user I might have misunderstood what it was telling me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As I understand it, the image area affects the amount of the sensor which is used? Is that correct?

Yes. That's correct. The 1.3x setting reduces the area of the sensor used from 23.5 x 15.6 mm to 18.8 x 12.5 mm. (see: [Nikon D7100 product page](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d7100/features01.htm#a10)).

> The photos were taken as RAW (NEF), and the raw images suggest that the pixel count is the same between images with/without the image area set wrong.

This is incorrect. If 1.3x is set, you get about 18MP, vs. the 24MP of the full sensor.

> Is this fixable in post processing? Or are the photo subjects permanently decapitated?

Sorry, but the subjects are permanently decapitated, as the "cropping" was done at the sensor. It may be worthwhile to point out to your MIL the crop box that appears in the viewfinder in 1.3x mode, although she's probably figured it out already.

Comment: What I suspected - at least it's corrected for future photos.